# Telephony package build failed

Tags: flutter, dart, sms, telephony

In my new Flutter app I imported [Telephony](https://pub.dev/packages/telephony) package:

```
telephony: ^0.1.3
```

But build files with exception:

```
Users/{user}/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/telephony-0.1.3/android/src/main/kotlin/com/shounakmulay/telephony/sms/SmsMethodCallHandler.kt: (52, 62): Expecting a parameter declaration

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':telephony:compileDebugKotlin'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/shounakmulay/Telephony/issues/84#issuecomment-844464725) answer I changed my kotlin version in `android/build.gradle` to

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.10'
```